# Why isn't my Themeroller theme rendering any CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, themes, icefaces

I've been playing with ICEfaces ACE components and I'm intrigued by the Jquery Themeroller support. I followed the instructions here: http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Creating+a+Custom+ThemeRoller+Theme but when I run my application, no CSS styling is present. It would seem I made a mistake in step 10 of the "prepare" stage, but I've checked and double-checked my theme.css file to make sure it's JSF-compliant.

I've uploaded my theme jar, and I was hoping someone might take a look at it and let me know where I've gone awry. Thanks!

JAR: http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21138.page

Crosspost: http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21138.page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this again the other day and decided to omit steps 9 and 10 on the [wiki guide](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Creating+a+Custom+ThemeRoller+Theme), and it worked perfectly. Apparently the the wiki is out of date at this time.

For reference, the working ThemeRoller jar can be downloaded here: http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/downloadAttach/4152.page

I've only modified file and directory names, and not file content.